# Horizontal slide to a certain length - iOS

Tags: ios, mobile

I have a view which contains a button named inbox. When i click on inbox button , number of uiviews appear depending on the count of inbox messages. Code is:

```
     int t=0;
     for(int i=0;i<countOfInboxMessages;i++){
         UIView *inboxView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, t, 309,80)];
         inboxView.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
         [inbox addObject:inboxView];
         [viewInbox addSubview:inboxView];
        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,4,250,20)];
         titleLabel.text = messageTitle[i];
       UILabel *createdDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,17,250,20)];
         createdDateLabel.text = createdDate[i];
         createdDateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:8];
         createdDateLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

         [inboxView addSubview:createdDateLabel];
         [inboxView addSubview:titleLabel];
          inboxView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
             UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
             swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
             [inboxView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

         t+=83;
     }
```

Say the value of countOfInboxMessages is 4. I would get 4 inboxViews. Now the task is I need to add swipe gesture to each inbox view. I am using the code:

```
        inboxView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
         swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
         [inboxView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

But the inbox views are not sliding. What could be the reason?

Comment: So what is your problem? I mean what you want?

Comment: The inboxViews are not sliding..what could be the reason?

Comment: Put your code of `handleSwipe:`?

Comment: - (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"swipeDetected");
    
}

Comment: So your handleSwipe: is not calling on your swipe gesture or you want the code to slide your inboxViews?

Comment: I think both..I mean no swipe is being detected..Main issue is..I want my code to slide my inboxViews

Comment: Put `titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;` and `createdDateLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;` default is `NO`.

Comment: No use..I even tried to hide all the labels and slide an empty inboxView..but there is no slide being detected.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem in your code. Where are you putting your swipeGesture code in your for loop?

Comment: I showed it in my edited question now

Comment: I had tried your code by just replacing single line [viewInbox addSubview:inboxView]; with [self.view addSubview:inboxView]; and it works fine so what is your viewInbox? may be you should use [viewInbox setUserInteractionEnable:YES];

Comment: hey...sorry for the delay..viewInbox is my scroll view on which inboxViews get placed once they get loaded.